# Ejecutar función de Main Activity desde una clase

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un interfaz que agrega javascript a una pagina de youtube, específicamente agrego un evento onclick, a el texto de descripción del primer video, del home principal de la pagina de youtube, este evento ejecuta la función getUrl pasandole la url del video satisfactoriamente

Para ello, tengo una clase MainWebView. Lo deseo ahora es poder ejecutar una función de la Main Activity desde ella.
Para fragmentos uso.

```
(activity as MainActivity?)?.changePage("https://google.com")
```

Sin embargo en la clase no función, ya que no se puede utilizar activity

**CLASE**

```
class MainWebView@JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : WebView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    init {
        setUpWebView()
    }


    fun exceuteJavascriptFunction(javascript: String) {
        this.evaluateJavascript(javascript, null)
    }

    ......
    .....
 private fun setUpWebView() {
      
        this.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        this.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
        this.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        this.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        this.addJavascriptInterface(JavaScriptInterface(), "AndroidJavaScriptToKotlin")

        this.loadUrl("https://m.youtube.com/")
    }

 
    
    private inner class JavaScriptInterface {
        @JavascriptInterface
        fun getUrl(url: String){
                //URL OBTENIDA SATISFACTORIAMENTE, CUANDO SE HACE CLIC EN EL TEXTO DEL VIDEO
                //AQUI IRIA LA FUNCION
                //(activity as MainActivity?)?.changePage(url) 
        }
    }

    inner class WebViewClient : android.webkit.WebViewClient() {
    override fun onLoadResource(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        super.onLoadResource(view, url)
        exceuteJavascriptFunction(mainJavaScript)
        
    }

   var mainJavaScript = "" +
        "function getUrl() {\n" +
        "   document.querySelector('.large-media-item-metadata a').setAttribute(\"onclick\", \"javascript: AndroidJavaScriptToKotlin.getUrl(document.querySelector('.large-media-item-metadata a').href)\");\n" +
        "};\n" +
        "getUrl();"
   }
}
```

Entonces como puedo ejecutar una función de la MainActivity desde :

```
private inner class JavaScriptInterface {
        @JavascriptInterface
        fun getUrl(url: String){
                //URL OBTENIDA SATISFACTORIAMENTE, CUANDO SE HACE CLIC EN EL TEXTO DEL VIDEO
                //AQUI IRIA LA FUNCION
                //(activity as MainActivity?)?.changePage(url) 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debes agregar un método en tu webView que te permita setear el callback y luego llamarlo desde la activity. Quedaría algo como esto

```
// en tu activity
val mainWebView: MainWebView = findViewById(R.id.mainWebView)
mainWebView.setOnVideoClickListener{ url ->
    changePage(url)
}
```

yo lo haría así:

```
class MainWebView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : WebView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    init {
        setUpWebView()
    }

    private fun setUpWebView() {
        webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onLoadResource(view: WebView, url: String?) {
                super.onLoadResource(view, url)
                view.evaluateJavascript(GET_URL, null)
            }
        }
        webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
        settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        loadUrl("https://m.youtube.com/")
    }

    fun interface OnVideoClickListener {
        @JavascriptInterface
        fun onVideoClick(url: String)
    }

    fun setOnVideoClickListener(listener: OnVideoClickListener) {
        removeJavascriptInterface("OnVideoClickListener")
        addJavascriptInterface(listener, "OnVideoClickListener")
    }

}

private const val GET_URL = """
function getUrl() {
    document
        .querySelector('.large-media-item-metadata a')
        .setAttribute(
            "onclick",
            "javascript: OnVideoClickListener.onVideoClick(document.querySelector('.large-media-item-metadata a').href)"
        );      
};
getUrl();   
"""
```

Comment: Hola, necesito implementar algo similar nuevamente, y espero haber entendido. Podría detallar como se ejecuta changePage(url) si , setOnVideoClickListener no se llama en webView. Estoy un poco confundido, disculpe si digo algo tonto.

Comment: No estoy seguro de entender la pregunta. Es el mismo patrón que debes estar acostumbrado a ver, similar a cuando haces `button.setOnClickListener { }`. Se registra un callback que va a ser llamado por el webView en respuesta a algún evento. En este caso nombré al callback "OnVideoClickListener" y si bien no es llamado directamente por el webView, la función que creaste en js si lo hace. La parte de la función `getUrl` que hace que se ejecute es esta: `OnVideoClickListener.onVideoClick(...)`

Comment: Realice un pregunta, para explicar mejor mi problema, espero me pueda ayudar