# Ejecutar función de Fragment desde Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin

Estoy intentando ejecutar un función de un fragment desde mi adapter. Para ello me estoy guiando de la [siguiente respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/436909/207936).

**Adapter**

```
fun interface OnTouchClickListener {
    fun onTouchClick(numx: Int)
}

fun setOnTouchClickListener(listener: OnTouchClickListener) {
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.itemTouch.setOnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
        if(motionEvent.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            OnTouchClickListener {  }.onTouchClick(9)  //Aquí deseo que se llame a la función del fragmet
        false
    }

}
```

**Fragmet**

```
recyclerAdapter.setOnTouchClickListener{ num ->   
            Log.i("msj", num.toString())            //Tendría que ejecutarse esto pero no pasa
        }
```

Según  lo que he leído esto es

> una interfaz de método abstracto único (SAM)

He visto diversos ejemplos sin embargo no logro hacer que funcionen en este caso.

Comment: no te sirvió mi respuesta?

Comment: Olvide aceptar la respuesta, funciono perfecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te explicaré lo que está sucediendo en tu app:

1. El fragment crea un objeto que implementa la interfaz `OnTouchClickListener` y lo pasa como argumento al método `setOnTouchClickListener` del adapter.

   ```
   recyclerAdapter.setOnTouchClickListener { num ->
       Log.i("msj", num.toString())
   }
   ```
2. Este método no hace nada y como resultado el listener que recibió deja de existir

   ```
   fun setOnTouchClickListener(listener: OnTouchClickListener) {}
   ```
3. Más adelante el adapter crea otro `OnTouchClickListener` (que nada tiene que ver con el anterior) y llama a su función `onTouchClick`. Es decir, ejecuta lo que está dentro de las llaves `{}` que en este caso es nada.

   ```
   OnTouchClickListener {  }.onTouchClick(9)
   ```

**Solución**: ejecutar el método `onTouchClick` del listener que recibiste

```
private var onTouchClickListener = OnTouchClickListener { } // default listener

fun setOnTouchClickListener(listener: OnTouchClickListener) {
    onTouchClickListener = listener
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    ...
    onTouchClickListener.onTouchClick(9)
}
```

Otra solución es reemplazar la interfaz por una lambda. De esta forma te ahorras la interfaz y también el método `setOnTouchClickListener`

```
class ExampleAdapter(val onTouch: (Int) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        ...
        onTouch(9)
    }
    ...
}
```

Entonces en el fragment puedes crear el callback junto con el adapter usando la sintaxis para [trailing lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas)

```
recyclerView.adapter = ExampleAdapter { num ->
    Log.i("msj", num.toString())
}
```